# Why isn't my class recognizing the iostream class inside my main.cpp although I included iostream?

Tags: c++, class, oop

So I was practicing OOPS and was trying to understand private and public.For this I created a different file in sources folder of my project(btw I am using Code::Blocks) like this:

```
+--Sources
  +--main.cpp
  +--student.cpp
```

main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "student.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    Student s1;

    s1.age = 20;

    s1.rollNo = 101;

    s1.display();

}
```

student.cpp :

```
class Student{
public:
    int rollNo;

private:
    int age;

public:
    void display(){
        cout << age << " " << rollNo << endl;

    }
};
```

Edited student.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>

class Student{
public:
    int rollNo;

private:
    int age;

public:
    void display(){
        std::cout << age << " " << rollNo << std::endl;

    }
};
```

And this is giving me the following errors:

```
error: 'endl' was not declared in this scope
error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
error: 'int Student::age' is private within this context
```

From what I understand,first two errors are due to the student.cpp not recognizing iostream headers.Is there different way to work with classes in code::blocks and if not what else can I use?

Also why am I getting third error,since I am trying to access `age` using a different function(`display`) which is public inside the `Student` class?

Comment: The third error is because you're trying to access `age` from inside `main()`

Comment: order of `using namespace std` matters. Put it before your `#include "student.cpp"`, or even inside

Comment: Use `std::cout` and `std::endl`.

Comment: @fukanchik shouldn't include .cpp at all

Comment: @alfC So when I use ```std::cout``` and ```std::endl```, it is still giving an error and gives a node to include iostream.So should I include iostream in student.cpp also?

Comment: Why does this happen? Odds are your build tool noticed the presence of student.cpp and did the what it always does with .cpp files: It compiled the .cpp file. Since student.cpp doesn't have an `include` for `iostream`, when compiled on its own it can't find the contents of iostream. When you fix this problem by adding `#include <iostream>` you will likely find you have linking problems as the output of student.cpp and main.cpp both define the same things. These are but two reasons why you should not include cpp files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are too many issues with the organization of this code that lead you to the problem.
Here it is a list of things to fix:

1. Never use naked `using namespace std;` (outside a well defined [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#C++)). Using it "globally" (like you did) breaks encapsulation (in some sense) by changing the meaning of code far away. The puzzling behavior is only one of the consequences.
2. `cpp` files are never `#include`d. [`cpp`s are for implementation and `hpp`s are for declaration (and maybe some implementation).](http://www.math.uaa.alaska.edu/%7Eafkjm/csce211/handouts/SeparateCompilation.pdf)
3. Your `student.cpp` file should be a `student.hpp` really
4. `student.hpp` should have its own "header" dependencies (`#include<iostream>` in `student.hpp`)
5. Say `std::cout` and `std::endl`, or `using std::cout; using std::endl;` (at worst `using namespace std`) but locally.

All above is about style and conventions. Besides that you have syntax error:

1. `age` should be public according to the desired usage in `main`.
2. Seems from the comments that your want to protect some internals of the class (like age), in that case you need to make them private, not access them from main, and have a public constructor for the class.

---

Ideally your code should look like this (not tested):

```
+--Sources
  +--main.cpp
  +--student.hpp
```

main.cpp :

```
#include "student.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    Student s1;

    s1.age = 20;

    s1.rollNo = 101;

    s1.display();

}
```

student.hpp :

```
#include <iostream>

class Student{
public:
    int rollNo;
    int age;
private:
    // was int age
public:
    void display(){
        using std::cout;
        cout<< age <<" "<< rollNo <<'\n'; // no need for endl
    }
};
```

student.cpp is not needed or might be empty.

Comment: Nice answer. To make it even better: help OP _understand_ the error messages by explaining what a scope is and what encapsulation means in C++. And for an A+ answer, explain (or link to) how to work with headers/implementation separation.

Comment: So I made some edits in ```student.cpp``` as you suggested.I tried using ```student.hpp``` but it says it doesn't recognize.Also I am still getting the third error,which is confusing me

Comment: The third error from the Question is  you made `age` private. You can't access it from outside your class. So trying `s1.age = 20;` in `int main()` is invalid and the compiler is correct.

Comment: @drescherjm but the ```display``` function isn't and since it is inside the same class as age,we should be able to access age through ```display```,which I tried to do there,but still its giving some errors

Comment: display is a class member is can access the private members of the Student class. `int main()` is not part of the `Student` class so it can't access `age`

Comment: @Xtense, if that is the case then change your code in main.

Comment: @drescherjm yes problem was in my main code (```s1.age = 20;```) and not actually the display function.Its working after making all the changes

Comment: @alfC Codeblocks provides functionality to add classes by adding a header file which come pre-eqipped with header files like iostream.Should I go with that or should I try to create my own header file?

Comment: @Xtense, as a beginner,  follow what the IDE tells you (it is probably correct) until you have some experience. Later you will realize that you don't need an IDE really.

Comment: @alfC appreciated,I came for a small doubt but learned a lot of things and mistakes here